# Generating SQLAlchemy KEY clauses for MySQL CREATE TABLE

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

If I have a declarative model:

```
class Foo(Base):
  id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
  bar = Column(INTEGER, index=yes)
```

...and I run

```
print(CreateTable(Foo.__table__).compile(db.engine))  # MySQL engine
```

...I see

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bar INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  # KEY `bar` (`bar`)  <-- this clause is never generated
);
```

What's missing from my model to create this clause? I'm finding it difficult to Google for because I get noisy results about foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the SQLAlchemy test suite for the MySQL dialect, there isn't actually a way to do this.